# How to restrict access to subset of data in Firebase realtime database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm developing an Android App where my user is authenticated through FirebaseAuth.

My user has to set in shared preferences the ID of a controller box. Once done, the app is able (and authorized) to read/write data on this particular controller box in the realtime database.

Currently I don't know how to define security rules based on the user ID AND the ID of the controller box.

My database looks like this:

```
controllers
    CID1
        data
    CID2
        data
```

For the moment, users are not implemented in the database. My idea would be to assign a controller to one to many user IDs (the ones generated by Firebase Auth), something like this:

```
controllers
    CID1
        data
        members
            UID1
            UID2
    CID2
        data
        members
            UID3
            UID4
```

In this example users with UID3 & 4 should have access to controller CID2 only.
So I need a security rule authorizing only read/write to the relevant CID. I imagine something like that:

```
"rules":{
    "controllers":{
      "$controller":{
        ".write": "$auth.uid === $controller.child('members').child($auth.uid)..."
      }
    },
```

But if I do like that, my user cannot declare himself the controller ID he should have access to.

Do I need first to create a users node containing the CID declarations of my users ?

```
controllers
    CID1
        data
        members
            UID1
            UID2
    CID2
        data
        members
            UID3
            UID4

users
    UID1
       CID1
    UID3
       CID2
...
```

**UPDATE:**
Let's try to give more meaning to the question above through a user story. Let say I'm a vendor of the controller; I dispatch the controller with its unique serial number (CID). As the vendor, I add the controller to the database (controllers > CIDx & the default data structure). The user, after receiving the controller, will install the app and authentify through his google account. Then, the user will enter the unique serial number (CID) in order to connect to the controller. Different users (authenticated, this is a pre requisite) can connect to a same controller. The user shall be able to read info from the controller (read in the DB) and submit orders to the controller (write in the DB).

I want to avoid a malicious user to parse the full db, then retrieve all controller unique IDs and then take the control in place of my users.

Comment: You question does not show how the user ID is implemented in your database. What are criteria?

Comment: Hi Jay, I tried to elaborate more on my problem. Let me know if my question is still unclear!

Comment: That's a lot better but there appears to be a logic issue. Stating *my user cannot declare himself the controller ID he should have access to* would indicate that any user can declare themselves access to any controller at any time. That would mean *all* users have access to *all* controllers - therefore rules would not be needed since any user can access any controller.

Comment: Yes you are right, they declare themselves the controller they have. On each controller there is a Unique ID in this format: 3f5a901a-0955-11e8-a379-4a22b170e406. So the chance to get a correct controller ID without knowing it seems very low. I just want a security rule avoiding to parse the whole controllers database and retrieve the different IDs.

Comment: The question is still a bit unclear; It seems users select controllers, and they can select any controller at any time. So there would be no need for rules, parsing or any other interaction other than just storing that users UID with the controller they selected or vice-versa where the controller ID would be stored with the user. If may help if you can explain what you're trying to*prevent* happening. Update the question and we'll take a look.

Comment: Sorry Jay, I missed your comment. I included a new user story to clarify better (I hope), the problematics. For the time being, I store the controller unique ID in the shared preferences of the app but I'm not confident with this approach, that's why I'd like to associate the controller to 1..n users.